# Prevent line break between short words

Tags: html, css

How to make automatically prevention of line breaks between short words consisting of less than 4 characters?

```
For example this piece of
text is
formatted not ideally
```

```
For example this piece of text
is formatted ideally
```

Comment: You can't with CSS...it's all or nothing. You *might (probably can)* be able to do this with Js but without an understandable *reason* for this requirement it's using a sledgehammer to crush a nut of unknown size.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this: `word-break:keep-all;` it prevents words from breaking between letters.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not about what I mean. I mean preventing line breaks between short words, not word breaks. I use nbsp for that purpose now, but I should use too much nbsp's in texts...

Comment: In that case, just change the width. I'm not sure I answered your question, but if you give me more detail I can help.